# classic asp - javascript array populated by vbscript drop down list

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, asp-classic, vbscript

I need to create a javascript array which is populated based on drop down lists' (more than one) selected values, except each drop down list has the same name because they are created in a for loop. Right now I have:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     var array = [];
     var e = document.getElementById("phItemStatusID").value; //returns first ddl value
</script>
```

and later in the asp code is my drop down list which is populated from a database using VBScript:

```
<%for i = 0 to UBound(photoItemsArray,2)%> //for each item, generate DDL
<select name="phItemStatusID">
    itemStatusID = photoItemsArray(6,i) //get current selected value
    for j = 0 to UBound(photoStatusesArray,2)%> //for each possible status
    <option value="<%=photoStatusesArray(0,j)%>"
            <%if photoStatusesArray(0,j) = itemStatusID then%> 
                selected
            <%end if%>>
            <%=photoStatusesArray(1,j)%>
        </option>
    <%next%>
</select>
next%>
```

This works in situations where there is only one dropdown list generated.  The problem I'm running into involves instances where there is more than one drop down list with the name `phItemStatusID`.

`var e = document.getElementById("phItemStatusID").value;` only returns the first drop down list's values and the others are ignored.  How do I obtain them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("phItemStatusID").value` will get the value of first element with an ID of "phItemStatusID" because IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique.

If you want to get the value of a second box, use a different ID.

Comment: Is there no way to loop through each generated phItemStatusID?  in vbscript you can use:    newPhotoItemStatusID = Request.Form("phItemStatusID")(i) where "i" is which dropdownlist you want the value for.

Comment: For starters: you're mixing up the functions of element NAMEs and IDs. Your code will not work until you straighten this out.

Comment: OH! I did not read your comment carefully enough. I'll give this a shot. Thanks!