# How do I convert a classic .ASP VB multidimensional array (from a recordset) for use in a javascript .js file?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, vbscript, asp-classic

The VB multidimensional array (arrHotelsProdCols) is created in classic .ASP vb thus:

```
strSQLHotelsProdCols = "SELECT * FROM qryHotelProdCols"
rsHotelsProdCols.Open strSQLHotelsProdCols, ConString
arrHotelsProdCols = rsHotelsProdCols.GetRows
```

The VB array works fine, over 600 rows, 4 cols. I can loop through it and display it in a table in the source .asp file html, etc.

I want to add a function to my existing validateform.js ‘included’ file that will fire onchange of one dropdown in an existing form in the same .asp file as the VB multidimensional array, search for a unique value and populate other fields in the form with other values on the same row in the multidimensional array – that part is not so difficult for me and is another question if I get stuck when I get there.

1) How do I convert and pass my VB multidimensional array to a javascript array for use in my validateform.js file?

Comment: can you join it on a special char and split the string on the same char in JS?

Comment: Simply have the VBScript write the JavaScript to the page initialize the array. See an similar question where he is using an array to populate a drop down.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672855/classic-asp-javascript-array-populated-by-vbscript-drop-down-list?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not seeing how this reply works or how I will access the JS array from within the .js file?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanations

In fact, as your question is stating, a **VB Array CAN BE multidimensional**.
But the **JScript Arrays CANNOT BE multidimensional : They are only one-dimension**.
(see. https://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/arrays)

### Solution

So, the solution is to list all the elements of your JScript one-dimension array, and try to *detect when you have reached a new "Row"*. How can we know that ? We can simply know that when the **RowNumber *Modulus* NumberOfColumns** is Zero, then it IS in fact a new row.
This may seem a bit "hacky", but it is 100% fully functional, even in a production environment :-)
Here is the source code of the VBScript part, and of the JScript part :

## The VBScript Part

```
<%
'Declare SQL Statement
Dim strSQLHotelsProdCols
strSQLHotelsProdCols = "SELECT * FROM qryHotelProdCols"

'Execute SQL Statement
rsHotelsProdCols.Open strSQLHotelsProdCols, ConString

'Populate Two-Dimensional VB Array
arrHotelsProdCols = rsHotelsProdCols.GetRows
%>
```

## The JScript Part

```
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">

    //Convert a VBScript Two-Dimensional array => To => JScript One-Dimensional array
    //Yes : Infortunately, JScript can only manage 1-Dimension Arrays !
    var tmp_VBArray = new VBArray(arrHotelsProdCols);
    var tmp_VBArrayInJs = (tmp_VBArray).toArray();

    //As all the "VB columns" (2-dimension array) have been converted into "JS rows" (1-dimension array),
    //We will manually detect when a new Row has started using the modulus (%) operator :-)

    //For each row in the One-Dimension JScript array
    for (var iRow = 0; iRow < tmp_VBArrayInJs.length; iRow++) {

        //Test if a new row has started
        var testNewRow = (iRow + 1) % (tmp_VBArray.ubound(1) + 1);

        //If a new row is detected
        if (testNewRow == true){
            response.write('<br>=> NEW ROW STARTED<br>');
        }

        //Write the fields
        response.write('<strong>'+iRow+'. </strong>');
        response.write(tmp_VBArrayInJs[iRow] + '<br>');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

From Help.
But I'd just give jscript the recordset.

**VBArray Object (JScript 5.6)**

Provides access to Visual Basic safe arrays.

```
varName = new VBArray(safeArray)
```

**Arguments**

*varName*

> Required. The variable name to which the VBArray is assigned.

*safeArray*

> Required. A VBArray value.

**Remarks**

> VBArrays are read-only, and cannot be created directly. The safeArray argument must have obtained a VBArray value before being passed to the VBArray constructor. This can only be done by retrieving the value from an existing ActiveX or other object.
>
> VBArrays can have multiple dimensions. The indices of each dimension can be different. The dimensions method retrieves the number of dimensions in the array; the lbound and ubound methods retrieve the range of indices used by each dimension.
>
> **Example**
>
> The following example consists of three parts. The first part is VBScript code to create a Visual Basic safe array. The second part is JScript code that converts the Visual Basic safe array to a JScript array. Both of these parts go into the  section of an HTML page. The third part is the JScript code that goes in the  section to run the other two parts.

```
<HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

<!--

Function CreateVBArray()

   Dim i, j, k

   Dim a(2, 2)

   k = 1

   For i = 0 To 2

      For j = 0 To 2

         a(j, i) = k

         document.writeln(k)

         k = k + 1

      Next

      document.writeln("vbCRLF")

   Next

   CreateVBArray = a

End Function

-->

</SCRIPT>



<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript">

<!--

function VBArrayTest(vbarray){

   var a = new VBArray(vbarray);

   var b = a.toArray();

   var i;

   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 

   {

      document.writeln(b[i]);

   }

}

-->

</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>



<BODY>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript">

<!--

   VBArrayTest(CreateVBArray());

-->

</SCRIPT>

</BODY>
```

> **Properties**
>
> The VBArray object has no properties.
>
> **Methods**

```
dimensions Method | getItem Method | lbound Method | toArray Method | ubound Method
```

> **Requirements**
>
> Version 3

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not seeing how this reply works or how I will access the JS array from within the .js file? I cannot even fathom continuity between these three 'sections'.